# Why is my question opinion-based/off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Recently I posted a question that was marked as opinion-based. So I revised it to remove anything I could possibly associate with opinion. After that the question was deleted, still marked as opinion-based.

Please explain why it is opinion based, so I can make appropriate questions in the future. Here is the text of the deleted revision:

> Title: Developing a desktop app with 3D graphics?
>
> For Windows 10 desktop C# application development, what IDE + 3d graphics
>   library will allow me to step into individual lines of my custom
>   shader code and
>
> - Be able to set breakpoints in shader code
> - Edit and continue
> - Move program counter backwards
>
> or at least some of those? And is there a hello world example for it?

Comment: Can you please clarify if you disagree with closure or you disagree with picking somewhat not ideal closure reason? It looks like straight recommendation request and should have been closed as such (make sure to review https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic: "to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow")...

Comment: As the close text says - _"[this question is] seeking recommendations for books, software libraries, or other off-site resources. This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers."_

Comment: There is a specific SE site for [software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), although you should still go through their help center to know how to ask a proper question there.

Comment: This will have been closed regardless. It's definitely not opinion based, but it is asking for a recommendation (which does mention opinion-based answers in the text as mentioned in another comment). Perhaps you mixed the 2 reasons up?

Comment: After reading the answers/comments here I am no longer disagreeing with the closure.  The key misunderstanding was that asking for the **existence of tools** matching specific debugging requirements counts as opinion seeking.  What I should be asking for here is how to **use a particular tool or language feature**.  https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ seems to be indeed a better forum to ask my question at.

Answer (score 10):

The question in current form is a request for a recommendation and should be closed as such. This is covered in

https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Note that there are two close reasons that mention "opinions"

- "Primarily opinion based" covered in https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask generally "what option between several approaches you recommend". This is the close vote reason generally referred as "closed as opinion based".
- "Recommendation" - tools/library recommendations as opposed to programming tools/libraries *usage* which is on-topic.

For this particular question you really seem to be looking for tools recommendation - it may be on-topic on special SE site - [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). Make sure to carefully review they [help](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help) to see if any more information is needed before you ask it there.

Alternatively you can ask whether a particular tool supports the functionality you are looking for. Something like "How to debug DirectX shader in Visual Studio 10 (community edition)". If you are looking for DirectX or Unity3d shaders you may also consider https://gamedev.stackexchange.com to search/ask that question (again check [help](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and don't ask for recommendations). If you are looking for WPF shaders SO is the right site.